# Python: declare input as variable (specifically, dictionary)

Tags: python, string, variables, dictionary, input

New to Python and programming in general, and maybe I'm asking the question wrong, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. 
So, I'm trying to take an input:

```
user = input('What is your character's name?")
```

And define it as a dictionary to then be added to as they add stats, program does math for derived stats and adds to them, that type of stuff.

So, if the input is 'John Doe', and I strip the whitespace out:

```
usr = ''.join(user.split())
```

How do I then take the resulting string 'JohnDoe', and define it as a dictionary type? I'm keeping this in program to get more comfortable with it, then I'll eventually be looking to create files that it will load/save for different users with a GUI and everything. But that's very long term right now. I do take this and print a formatted sheet using the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: For starters, you're missing a doublequote in your first code line

Comment: What do you mean by *define it as a dictionary type*? also `usr = user.replace(' ', '')` is better

Comment: What do you want your dictionary to look like?  What will the keys be?   (PS. instead of split and join to remove whitespace, try [`user.replace(' ', '')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace))

Comment: I think you want something like `people[usr] = {}` so that you can dynamically create containers for more than one entry, but it's hard to tell.  Also, `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @user3100115, @dsh that doesn't remove tabs and newline. You should use `re.sub(r'\s+', '', user)`.

Comment: @op did you mean that  you want 'JohnDoe' to be a key in a dictionary whose value is another dictionary?

Comment: no, I want a dictionary with variable as JohnDoe. so the input is stripped, then JohnDoe = dict(), but I want a function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
character_dict = {'Name': 'None', 'Class': 'None'}

character_dict['Name'] = str(raw_input('Enter a Character Name: '))
character_dict['Class'] = str(raw_input('Choose a Class: '))

print ("The hero " + character_dict['Name'] + " is a level 0 " + character_dict['Class'])
```

Comment: not quite what I am looking for, I want the input as the dictionary variable, so when input is 'John Doe', then stripped to 'JohnDoe', I now want a way to do JohnDoe = dict()

Comment: So you want the name of the variable (in this case a dictionary) to be input by the user?

Comment: correct, sorry I took forever to respond, moved onto another project, but an answer to this would help me nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will give you a bit of an idea how a dictonary works:

```
# Create an empty dictornary. 
data = dict()
# Lets put some examples in it this time. 
# Lets say, UserName:Password
data = {'Sara':'BrownCat2','John':'HelloKitty77','Magnus':'AngryCar101'}

# Show what we have in the dictonay.
print(data) 

# Inserting/Updating
data['John']='Yello1'
# Deleting 
del data['Magnus']

# Show what we have in the dictonay.
print(data) 

# Empty the whole dictonary 
data.clear()

# Show what we have in the dictonay.
print(data)
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not quite it. I'm wanting the input to become the variable itself. so instead of data, it would be <result of an input> = dict()